# React Typescript. The right way to push new objects form api to array with existing objects without repeating them

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-state

I have a custom hook where I call 16 subreddits at the time because I want to implement an infinite scroll. When the url page parameter change I want to add the new data to the array witch then I map. But I cant find the right way to do it with typescript. Can some of you guys show me the right way?

**The types:**

```
export type Subreddits = [Subreddit];
export type Subreddit = {
id: string;
title: string;
description: string;
};
```

**The Hook:**

```
function useSubreddit() {
  let [subredditData, setSubredditData] = useState<any>([]);
  const [loadingSubbredits, setLoadingSubreddits] = useState(false);
  const [subredditError, setSubredditError] = useState(null);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const url =
    "https://6040c786f34cf600173c8cb7.mockapi.io/subreddits?page=1&limit=16";

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoadingSubreddits(true);
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        setSubredditData(
          (subredditData = [ new Set([...subredditData, ...response.data])])
        );
        dispatch(setSubredditsData(response.data));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setSubredditError(err);
      })
      .finally(() => setLoadingSubreddits(false));
  }, [url]);

  return { loadingSubbredits, subredditError, subredditData };
}

export default useSubreddit;
```

Comment: What's ts error did you get?

Comment: Set will not help due to array/response has object values, you can store results as key value objects to distinct the retrieving results.

Comment: I just need the right way to do it because i fell this is not it. even if i call only 5 elements form the api it still shows 10 , and i don't think just by setting the Set it would be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to add new item to set:

```
setSubredditData((
    { subredditData }) => ({
        subredditData: new Set(subredditData).add(response.data)
      })
);
```

Comment: It gives me this error "Binding element 'subredditData' implicitly has an 'any' type."

Answer (score 0):

Change `subredditData` type to `Array`

```
const [subredditData, setSubredditData] = useState<Array>([])
```

Then use;

```
setSubredditData(subredditData => [...subredditData, ...response.data])
```

Ideally you should define the type of response object so Typescript knows what kind of data it has;

```
.then((response: ResponseType) => {
```

Working example: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-72159072-8md33i?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: This way it works but still it shows me the data duplicated, if I give it a limit of 4 (/subreddits?page=1&limit=4) it shows 8 , each object twice

Comment: Data should not be duplicated. I've added working example, can you check it?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function useSubreddit() {
  let [subredditData, setSubredditData] = useState({});
  const [loadingSubbredits, setLoadingSubreddits] = useState(false);
  const [subredditError, setSubredditError] = useState(null);
  //console.log(subredditData);
  const url =
    "https://6040c786f34cf600173c8cb7.mockapi.io/subreddits?page=1&limit=16";

  useEffect(() => { 
    setLoadingSubreddits(true);
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        const result = response.data?.reduce((prev,curr) => ({ ...prev, ...{ [curr.id]: curr }}),{});
       
        setSubredditData((subredditData) => ({ ...subredditData, ...result }));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setSubredditError(err);
      })
      .finally(() => setLoadingSubreddits(false));
  }, [url]);

  return { loadingSubbredits, subredditError, subredditData:Object.values(subredditData) };
}

export default useSubreddit;
```

working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-brown-9nf7ne?file=/src/App.js

Comment: In This case subredditData returns an empty object

Comment: tested: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-brown-9nf7ne?file=/src/useSubreddit.js

Answer (score 0):

**I found the solution**

```
function useSubreddit() {
  const [subredditData, setSubredditData] = useState<Array<any>>([])
  const [loadingSubbredits, setLoadingSubreddits] = useState(false);
  const [subredditError, setSubredditError] = useState(null);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const url =
    "https://6040c786f34cf600173c8cb7.mockapi.io/subreddits?page=1&limit=4";

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoadingSubreddits(true);
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then((response: SubredditsResponse) => {
        setSubredditData(Array.from( new Set([ ...subredditData, ...response.data])))
        dispatch(setSubredditsData(response.data));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setSubredditError(err);
      })
      .finally(() => setLoadingSubreddits(false));
  }, [url]);

  return { loadingSubbredits, subredditError, subredditData };
}

export default useSubreddit;
```

Thank you for your help guys

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).